# Project Server Enterprise Custom Fields Always result null

Tags: progressive-web-apps, custom-field-type, ms-project-server-2016

i have created enterprise custom fields (formula) for  Project server 2016 
it was working before the issue now is all formula fields results null even i put fixed text or value of another built in field for example 
 and all formula working with  project professional with no problem and display the result OK

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the Calculate Project? or press Ctrl+F9 while in Project Professional.

Try to republish the project full - through Macro code. (Not standard publish).